# Optional Maven properties in profiles

Tags: maven

I have "web service test" project that I use for testing our web services.  I use maven profiles to generate the client for each web service like so:

```
<profile>
    <!-- to run: mvn clean cxf-codegen:wsdl2java -e -Dservice=single-sign-on -->
    <id>single-sign-on</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>service</name>
            <value>single-sign-on</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <ws.wsdl>http://example.com:8080/SingleSignOnService?wsdl</ws.wsdl>
        <ws.dir>src/generated/single-sign-on</ws.dir>
        <ws.package>com.example.single_sign_on</ws.package>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I use the cxf-codegen-plugin to actually generate the client:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${ws.dir}</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${ws.wsdl}</wsdl>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-frontend</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-npa</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>${ws.package}</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that I need to specify the package for a few of the web services so their objects don't conflict, but for most of the web services I don't need to.  So basically what I am trying to do is somehow optionally include the

```
<extraarg>-p</extraarg>
<extraarg>${ws.package}</extraarg>
```

part based on whether the profile has the <ws.package> property defined or not.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this can be done out of the box with maven, as it only merges the first level of of the `<configuration>` element, with any other configuration that you might have in a profile (and thus replacing the whole `<wsdlOptions>` element).

One solution, but only to make if the current state causes you enough pain, is to write your own version `cxf-codegen-plugin` where you can pass an extra `<myextraargs>` configuration at the top level of the `<config>`. For example

```
<profile>
    <id>single-sign-on</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>service</name>
            <value>single-sign-on</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- extra args for your plugin -->
        <my.extra.args>-p ${ws.package}</my.extra.args>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

-

```
<!-- generic test configuration>
<plugin>
    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${ws.dir}</sourceRoot>
        <myextraargs>${my.extra.args}</myextraargs>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${ws.wsdl}</wsdl>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>...</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
</plugin>
```

Then your plugin would be responsible for merging the extra args array that the real cfx plugin requires.

### edit

After writing the answer, I wonder if the CFX plugin complains if you pass empty `<extraarg>` elements. If it's ok, then you can define the variables in a profile and some profiles will have an empty value, for example

```
<!-- profile 1 -->
    <properties>
        <!-- ... -->
        <cfx.extra.property.1>-p</cfx.extra.property.1>
        <cfx.extra.property.2>${ws.package}</cfx.extra.property.2>
    </properties>
<!-- profile 2 -->
    <properties>
        <!-- ... -->
        <cfx.extra.property.1></cfx.extra.property.1>
        <cfx.extra.property.2></cfx.extra.property.2>
    </properties>
<!-- ... -->
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>...</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>${cfx.extra.property.1}</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>${cfx.extra.property.2}</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried passing empty parameters like you suggested in your edit, but it gave an error: "Unexpected argument", unfortunately.  I'll look at your other solution to see how feasible that is.